# Bootstrap 4 - How can I fit the column like size of content?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I do have this situation:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**What I would like to have is:**

- **Number 1:** Fit column width to the content / in that case to the imgage.
- **Number 2:** Fit the column width to the text "Title of Content"
- **Number 3:** Fit width of this column like 'the rest of width til end'. So be flexible.

**My HTML:**

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="row">        
        <div class="col-xl-3 .mx-auto text-center">
          <div class="row">              
              <div class="col-xl-1  bg-dark">
                 <img src="img/01_number_in_circular.svg" alt="Step 1">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-11 bg-success">
                  <h2>Title of Content</h2>
                  <p>Description Text in short form.</p>
              </div>              
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-9 bg-info">
            Column 3            
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I also have tried with `col-xl-*`, but it doesn't work.

Is there a class that I can apply for doing that?
I hope, you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below you have working example(run shippet in 'full window' mode). Based on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Result:

[image]
[image]

```css
.col1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.col2 {
    background-color: green;
}

.col3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-auto col1">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto col2">
      Variable width content
    </div>
    <div class="col col3">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-auto col1">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto col2">
      Variable width content
    </div>
    <div class="col col3">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-auto col1">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto col2">
      Variable width content ......
    </div>
    <div class="col col3">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-auto col1">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto col2">
      Variable width content .....................
    </div>
    <div class="col col3">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have updated my question, please check. Your solution works well, but only in the desktop version. In the mobile view, it looks not like that, how I would like to have. Maybe you can fix that. Thanks

Comment: In my snippet all works well :) You have a problem in your project. Unfortunately, I ca't help

Comment: OK I get it, the main difference is that you are using `col-md` instead of `col-xl` like in my question. Even that, thank you. :-)

Comment: You're welcome :)